# undefiend function or variable

Tags: matlab, function

I worte like that; I got an error message, " Undefined function or variable 'MATM'"
'MATM' is function and no probs in other function. How can i do that?

```
function FUNC 

global LNODS COORDI SHAPE NELEM DZETTA

for I=1:3
for J=1:4
    WORMX=zeros(I,J);
end
end

SHAPE=zeros(3,9);

for INODE=1:8
for IELEM=1:NELEM
IPOIN=abs(LNODS(IELEM,INODE));
for K=1:3
    GTOP=COORDI(IPOIN,K);
    GBOT=COORDI(IPOIN,K+4);
    GOSH=((1.0+0.91)*GTOP+(1.0-0.91)*GBOT)/2.0;
    for J=1:3
        WORMX(K,J)=WORMX(K,J)+GOSH*SHAPE(J,INODE);
    end
    WORMX(K,4)=WORMX(K,4)+SHAPE(1,INODE)*(GTOP-GBOT)/2.0;

end
end
end

MATM !---error message

end
```

Comment: Where is MATM defined? Is it an .m file? Is it in your current working directory?

Comment: The main program is 'MAIN.m' file and MATM is function in the MAIN.m. for example, function MAIN and function MATM is one file

Comment: And where is function FUNC?

Comment: MAIN.m includes Main furction, FUNC function and MATM function

Comment: Could you please post the control flow, as the question and the description seem to be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions (i.e. secondary functions within a file), are only visible within the file.  You'll need to move the matm function to its own file.