# Fortran to matlab 'undefined function error'

Tags: matlab, fortran, converters

I want to covert fortran to matlab.

**-fortran code**

```
   DO 20 I=1,3
   DO 20 J=1,4
20 WORMX(I,J)=0.0

   DO 24 INODE=1,8
   IPOIN=IABS(LNODS(IELEM,INODE0)
   DO 24 K=1,3
   GTOP=COORD(IPOIN,K)
   GBOT=COORD(IPOIN,K+4)
   GOSH=((1.0+ZETA)*GTOP+(1.0-ZETA)*GBOT)/2.0
   DO 22 J=1:3
22 WORMX(K,J)=WORMX(K,J)+GOSH*SHAPE(J,INODE)
24 WORMX(K,4)=WORMX(K,4)=WORMX(K,4)+SHAPE(1,INODE)*GTOP-BBOT)/2.0

   CALL MATM(2,5,0,1)
```

.
.
.
**-matlab code**

```
function FUNC 

global LNODS COORDI SHAPE NELEM DZETTA

for I=1:3
    for J=1:4
        WORMX=zeros(I,J);
    end
 end

 SHAPE=zeros(3,9);
 for INODE=1:8
     for IELEM=1:NELEM
         IPOIN=abs(LNODS(IELEM,INODE));
         for K=1:3
             GTOP=COORDI(IPOIN,K);
             GBOT=COORDI(IPOIN,K+4);
             GOSH=((1.0+0.91)*GTOP+(1.0-0.91)*GBOT)/2.0;
             for J=1:3
             WORMX(K,J)=WORMX(K,J)+GOSH*SHAPE(J,INODE);
             end
             WORMX(K,4)=WORMX(K,4)+SHAPE(1,INODE)*(GTOP-GBOT)/2.0;

         end
     end
 end

 MATM(2, 5, 0, 1)
```

.
.

I got an error message in matlab code,

```
"Undefined function or method 'MATM' for input arguments of type 'double'."
```

What's the problem in this code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477528/undefiend-function-or-variable ? MATM is not defined anywhere in your code, or you're not showing us where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your FORTRAN code calls a procedure `MATM`. If your FORTRAN code does not error, then presumably that procedure is defined somewhere.

Have you translated the procedure `MATM` into MATLAB yet? If not, then that is the issue - when MATLAB gets to the point `MATM(2, 5, 0, 1)` it fails, as the function `MATM` is not defined.

If you have already translated `MATM` to MATLAB, then the issue is probably that MATLAB cannot find your function `MATM`. Perhaps you need to add the location of `MATM` to your MATLAB path.

Answer (score 0):

I think MATM not being found because it is defined inside another functions m-file.

Have a look at the question and accepted answer to [Is it possible to define more than one function per file in MATLAB, and access them from outside that file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab).